# UISearchBarController stuck underneath NavigationBar Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to add a search bar to the navigation bar of my app, but it seems to be falling below my current navigation bar:

[image: My rightBarButtonItem 'Cancel' on top of the search controllers 'Cancel' button]

What I'm trying to achieve is for the SearchBar to sit next to the cancel button, where the cancel button dismisses the view controller only (i.e. isn't linked to the search bar). The style I'm trying to achieve is to have an 'x' button within the search bar to clear the text, as below:

[image: Example of what I'm trying to achieve, from the iPhone Clocks app World Clock page]

This is the current code I've got:

```
navigationItem.prompt = "Choose a City."
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(dismissPage))
let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
search.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
search.searchResultsUpdater = self
search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
navigationItem.searchController = search
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
//Required for UISearchBarController
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

If anyone could put me in the write direction I'd be really grateful - I've exhausted my Google searching as I'm not sure how to describe what I'm asking for!

Many thanks in advance,
Andy

Comment: remove any search bar added from the storyboard, and try again

Comment: Thank you - weirdly I've not added a search bar in the storyboard. All using the above code.